# threejs - How to rotate object on fixed world axis?

Tags: javascript, 3d

```js
function rotateGearModel(axis, value) {
 switch (axis) {
  case 'x':
   riduttore.rotation.x = parseFloat(value);
   $('#gmRotX').attr('value', parseFloat(value).toFixed(3));
   break;
  case 'y':
   riduttore.rotation.y = parseFloat(value);
   $('#gmRotY').attr('value', parseFloat(value).toFixed(3));
   break;
  case 'z':
   riduttore.rotation.z = parseFloat(value);
   $('#gmRotZ').attr('value', parseFloat(value).toFixed(3));
   break;
 }
}
```

I've experiencing some trouble with object rotation in threejs.
I have a scene with a Collada model that I need to rotate interactively (user have 1 slider for each axe, x y z).
If user follows euler order there are no problems, but if I try to rotate the model with following steps I get a "lost in space" experience :))

1. rotate on X object local axe (the rotation seems aligned with world axe);
2. rotate on Y object local axe (the rotation seems aligned with world axe);
3. rotate on Z object local axe (the rotation seems aligned with world axe);
4. change given rotation on Y axe (step 2) then I rotation seems not aligned with world axe.

So my problem is simply: how can I rotate object on a fixed world axis step by step? When I rotate object on its Y axe by 90°, the X local axe from horizontal become vertical, so now how can I rotate object on world X axe (Z object axe)?

Now I rotate my model with function above, where axis is a char identifying axe of rotation and value is in radians.

Thank you